# All total functions form a PRC class

Tags: computability

> A class of total functions is a *PRC class* if:
>
> 1. The class includes all projection functions $p_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = x_i$ and the initial functions $n(x) = 0$ and $s(x) = x+1$.
> 2. The class is closed under composition and primitive recursion.
>
> Prove that the class of all total functions is a PRC class.

Is it true if I say every total function is computable?
And then say because the class of computable functions is a PRC class, so is the class of total functions.

Comment: Not every total function is computable.

Comment: The exercise is much simpler. The closure operations in the definition of a PRC class all trivially hold for the class fo *all* functions.

Comment: Perhaps you can include the definition of *PRC class* (I had to look it up).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The PRC class definition : We call a class of total functions a PRC class if: 1. It includes initial functions 2. It is close under composition and recursion

Comment: @YuvalFilmus the initial functions are S(x) = x+1     n(x) =0.        And the projection functions

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks alot. I've got what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot say that every total function is computable, since that is not true. For example, the function $f(n)$ which returns $1$ if the $n$'th Turing machine halts and $0$ otherwise is *not* computable.

However, the question is much simpler. The definition of a PRC class specifies several closure properties, of the form: if so-and-so belong to the class, then such-and-such also belongs to the class (these include the "axioms", in which the premise is empty). Since the class of all (total) functions contains *all* functions, it automatically satisfies these constraints.